# Text to speech for selected text ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, text-to-speech

While a lot of options exist to read aloud text pasted to the command line, what's the best software/tool to achieve the same function for highlighted text? I am looking for something similar to mac OS but haven't been able to find anything.

Already tried this command :

```
bash -c "gespeaker --play-text=\"$(xsel | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n/ /;ta')\""
```

But doesn't work.Any suggestions?

Comment: Most I've ever gotten it two was two steps: 1. Manually copy selected text (i.e., Ctrl-C)
2. key binding for: ```bash -c "xsel --clipboard | espeak"``` One day I'll have to try to crack it.

Comment: Even I couldn't find anything better. If you do find something, let me know too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

user597291 here again (don't have an account). Figured out how to do it with a single keybinding.

You can use xclip to take the primary selected text (i.e. highlighted text), then pipe that into the clipboard.

From there use xsel to take the clipboard text and pipe that to espeak. I also recommend sanitizing newlines, otherwise espeak will only read the last paragraph.

**Method 1 (separate file):**

The way I do it, the keybinding calls a script that does all of this which looks like `sh ~/.custom-scripts/play-selected-text` in the keyboard binding command.

The script looks like this.

```
#! /bin/bash

xclip -out -selection primary | xclip -in -selection clipboard
xsel --clipboard | tr "\n" " " | espeak
```

**Method 2 (directly in keybind):**

If you don't need a separate folder for custom scripts, you can just put this into the keyboard binding command section.

```
xclip -out -selection primary | xclip -in -selection clipboard; xsel --clipboard | tr "\n" " " | espeak
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!  I also added a keyboard shortcut to run the above script on `Super+Shift+R` (similar to mac) . It runs `sh /path_to_script/play-text.sh` and works perfectly. Next step is to find a way to improve the sound and voice quality of espeak (too mechanical IMO)

Comment: Okay just realized, that directly pasting the your second command into the keyboard binding would've worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry. That was my fault for being unclear I was giving two methods. I've edited my answer to reflect that. Anyway, glad to help. It's something I've wanted for a while too.

Comment: This method didn't work for me :(

Comment: In latest Ubuntu (18.x) when you add this as keyboard shortcut command, wrap the above into `bash -c '` like so: `bash -c 'xclip -out -selection primary | tr "\n" " " | espeak'`

Answer (score 0):

Install the TTS `festival` and `xsel` to pipe the selected text.

```
$  sudo apt-get install festival
$  sudo apt-get install xsel

$  cat << eof > talk.sh
> #!/bin/bash
> xsel | festival --tts --pipe
> eof

$ chmod +x talk.sh
```

Now go to `settings`> `keyboard shortcuts` and `+` icon to create a new shortcut.
On the command field type in `/home/<your username>/talk.sh`

Done. Now you can select any text, press the shortcut you choose and Festival will read it for you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).